# How in pyqt change text in QPlainTextEdit() if slider's value is 1, and don't change if the value is 0?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
message = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
slider = QtGui.QSlider()
def slider_func():
    if slider.value() == 0:
       '''what to write here ?'''

    if slider.value() == 1:
        m = str(message.toPlainText())
        translated = ''
        i = len(m) - 1
        while i >= 0:
            translated = translated + m[i]
            i = i - 1
        message.setPlainText(translated)
QtCore.QObject.connect(slider, QtCore.SIGNAL('valueChanged(int)'),
                    slider_func)
```

When I set slider to the first tick, the text gets reversed. But when I set it to the begining the text is still reversed. I know that the problem is that once the text was changed it sets the text edit line. Any ideas how to solve it ? [Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drz5v.png), [Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdflE.png)

Comment: Are you really a programmer?? :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to watch the value of the slider, and modify a `QPlainText` when the value is at certain values.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.Qt import *
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.text = "Please enter some text"
        self.edit = QPlainTextEdit(self.text)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)

        slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        layout.addWidget(slider)
        slider.valueChanged.connect(self.change_value)

    def change_value(self, value):
        if value == 0:
            self.edit.setPlainText(self.text)
        elif value == 1:
            self.edit.setPlainText(self.text[::-1])
        elif value > 1:
            self.edit.setPlainText("Slider value is above 1, value: {0}".format(value))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the `QSlider.valueChanged` signal is emitted, the new value is carried with it. So in my slot `Window.change_value(self, value)` the `value` positional argument will always contain the new `QSlider` value; which allows you to test against it.

Comment: but the problem is when I change slider position and sets it back to 0, I get '"Slider value currently at 0'" instead of very first text "Slider value initialized at 0", dont you know how to fix IT ?

Comment: You can just set the text to be whatever you want it to be at 0. You could just change the line `self.edit.setPlainText("Slider value currently at 0")` to `self.edit.setPlainText("Slider value initialized at 0")`. Whatever string you have inside the `setPlainText(...)` will be what the text gets changed to.

Comment: This is not what I mean, try to change slider value to 1 and back to 0 and see what happens [code](http://pastebin.com/Mkdi6FJK). When slider is at 0 position the text is the same as it was on 1 position

Comment: So if I understand correctly at slider value 1 you want to display the text of slider value 0, but reversed. I edited my original answer to reflect that goal. All you have to do is assign the text for value 0 as an attribute `self.text`. Which you can then use to reverse when the slider is at value 1.